# Unexpected error using the sum function in a QoQ

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018, qoq

While attempting to run the following code

```
<cfquery name="Lev1CatTotal" dbtype="query">
    SELECT 
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM 
        ChartData
</cfquery>
```

This is the error message that's generated:

Query Of Queries runtime error. The aggregate function [SUM(expression)] cannot operate on an operand of type [JAVA_OBJECT]

This code works fine when aggregating smaller amounts.  However, these are the amount in the table I'm aggregating.  This particular query sums to over $5.7B.

| AMOUNT | FISCAL_YR | GOV_LEVEL1_CAT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 979241575.14 | 2019 | Charges for Services |
| 97218277.18 | 2019 | Charges to Other Governments |
| 233197655.52 | 2019 | Federal Aid |
| 329567996.81 | 2019 | Other Local Revenues |
| 86957092.75 | 2019 | Other Non-Property Taxes |
| 158997846.75 | 2019 | Other Real Property Tax Items |
| 371012673.89 | 2019 | Other Sources |
| 346575244.01 | 2019 | Proceeds of Debt |
| 1145011131.99 | 2019 | Real Property Taxes and Assessments |
| 945308275.55 | 2019 | Sales and Use Tax |
| 921087680.04 | 2019 | State Aid |
| 107357596.20 | 2019 | Use and Sale of Property |

Just to move forward, as a workaround, I recoded this as follows:

```
<cfset TOTAL = 0>
<cfloop query="ChartData">
    <cfset TOTAL = precisionEvaluate(TOTAL + AMOUNT)>
</cfloop>
```

Using [`precisionEvaluate()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/precisionevaluate.html), it casts the `TOTAL` to `BigDecimal` precision and avoids the error.  Does someone know of a QoQ solution using the `sum()` function to cast this to a big decimal and avoid using this workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: If you are just looking to avoid the loop you can use `ArraySum()`.  See example here https://trycf.com/gist/59edd579247e02f472f56df5e632b245/acf2021?theme=monokai.

Comment: @DanBracuk  I tried and `arraySum()` doesn't work.  Error message: Object of type class coldfusion.runtime.CFDouble cannot be used as an array.  Looks like your gist also errors on the `arraySum()` line as well.  However, this gives me food for thought and I'll look into somehow using it again tomorrow.  It's the end of my work day, so I'll start fresh tomorrow.

Comment: My gist throws an error with the latest Lucee engine but not with CFML 2018.

Comment: Where does *ChartData* come from, in the first place?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler This is inherited code, so I had to look into it.  It looks like it was created using `QueryNew()` and the original coder didn't specify the datatype of the `AMOUNT` column and he populated it with numeric values he queried separately from an Oracle database.  I'm not sure why he coded it the way he did, but I'm wondering if I specify the datatype on the `QueryNew()` statement, it could solve the issue.

Comment: @DanBracuk ok, yes.  After changing the runtime engine to ACF2018 on the gist, it does work without issues.  I'm a bit fried right now, so when my head is fresh tomorrow morning, I'll give it another go within my own source code.

Comment: @user12031119 I guess QueryNew uses varchar, if no type is provided

Comment: @BernhardDöbler you pointed me in the right direction.  I added data types to the `QueryNew()` statement and it corrected the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big thanks to @BernhardDöbler for getting me to look into where *ChartData* comes from.  Since this was inherited code, I had to look into this.  It turned out that *ChartData* was created with the following line of code.

```
<cfset ChartData = QueryNew("FISCAL_YR, GOV_LEVEL1_CAT, AMOUNT")>
```

I noticed, the original coder didn't specify any data types for his `QueryNew()` statement, so I modified the line of code to

```
<cfset ChartData = QueryNew("FISCAL_YR, GOV_LEVEL1_CAT, AMOUNT", "VarChar, VarChar, Double")>
```

Once I added the `Double` data type to the `AMOUNT` column, it corrected the error when I restored back to the original code of

```
<cfquery name="Lev1CatTotal" dbtype="query">
    SELECT 
        SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
    FROM 
        ChartData
</cfquery>
```

and I was able to remove my workaround code which performed the aggregation using a `<cfloop>`.